# how to start studing differential equations

Tags: mathematical-physics, differential

hello everyone I have trouble understanding differential equations, am in the second year of studying programing engineer this semester I have differential equations, and my level in math is so low am trying to do my best so my question is what subject should I understand before taking a differential equations course, because.

Comment: You should have some basic understanding of analysis (and linear algebra) to get started.

Comment: I know a little bit about  linear algebra like eigenvalues and eigenvector, matrix, gauss,  but sometimes there is a derivative equation and I did not have it in liner algebra so should I study calculus

Comment: If you don't know how to deal with derivatives yet, then of course you should start with calculus first. :)